# Printing values in steps

Tags: python, range

I am printing values in steps of 1, but I want to print in steps of 10.

```
Total = 11
for t in range(0, Total):
    print(t)
```

The current output is

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

The expected output is

```
0
10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use the [`step` argument](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-range) of the `range()` function:

```
for t in range(0, Total, 10):
```

> For a positive step, the contents of a range `r` are determined by the formula `r[i] = start + step*i` where `i >= 0` and `r[i] < stop`.
>
> For a negative step, the contents of the range are still determined by the formula `r[i] = start + step*i`, but the constraints are `i >= 0` and `r[i] > stop`.